# Axios FormAppend post method and node.js

Tags: node.js, axios

I trigger / upload in node.js by calling the submit function inside a class. But in Node.js, req.body is empty. In fact, I append data to FormData in the submit function and send it to node.js. Where am I doing the problem?

**Class**

```
submit(){
        const data = new FormData() 


        data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile)
        data.append('ID', uniqid())

        let url = "http://localhost:5000/upload";

       axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          }).then(res => {

          });
    }
```

**Node.js**

```
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {

 axios.post('https://....php', req.body, {
         
   }).then(function (response) {

  }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('errorserver', error);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put file after text like this.

```
    submit(){
        const data = new FormData() 


data.append('ID', uniqid())
data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile)

        let url = "http://localhost:5000/upload";

       axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          }).then(res => {

          });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. req.body feels empty again

Comment: try req.body.data once.

Comment: Make sure your app has a body parser: `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended : true}));

app.use(express.json());`

Comment: file will come in req.file where as text will come in req.body check with console.log once

Comment: Yes @Dan Levy is correct also check that once.

Comment: Do you have a file "body parser?" Something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty ?